# How can I monitor mem usage during a Python function call

Tags: python-3.x, memory

I have a Python function for which I would like to monitor memory usage over time, call it `foo`.

Note that I don't want to use an external profiler... I just want very simple statistics that I can append to a log file.

I would like to use the following function to perform the monitoring in a separate process while the body of `foo` is executing:

```
def monitor_mem(monitor_list, tic):
    while process_not_terminated:
        monitor_list.append(psutil.virtual_memory())
        time.sleep(tic)
```

The `foo` function would look something like this (note that `mp` is `multiprocessing` module):

```
def foo():
    # Start collecting system memory data
    monitor_list = []
    monitor_process = mp.Process(target=monitor_mem, args=(monitor_list, 0.5))
    monitor_process.start()

    # Do interesting stuff
    print('Doing interesting stuff!')
    time.sleep(5)

    # End collecting system memory data
    monitor_process.terminate()
    monitor_process.join()
    return monitor_list
```

I've played around with making the loop in `monitor_mem` a `while True`. That doesn't seem to work. I feel like I need to be able to send some sort of signal to stop the function... but I'm just not sure. Hopefully one of you all can look at my code example and give me some hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Queue instead of list when you working with threads and processes.

Example with Queue:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


def monitor_mem(monitor_queue):
    while True:
         monitor_queue.put(datetime.now())
         sleep(1)


queue = Queue()
process = Process(target=monitor_mem, args=(queue,))
process.daemon = True
process.start()

print("Doing something")
sleep(5)

process.terminate()
while not queue.empty():
    item = queue.get()
    print(item)
```